# Cells background color in SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchGetRequest Google Sheets

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Who know, how to get background color in BatchGetRequest?

In `GetRequest` I can use `GetRequest.IncludeGridData`, but in `BatchGetRequest` i don`t find similar parameters.

I want get background color with values in Google Sheet cells and than apply that values in Datagridview cells.

Comment: It's not possible to retrieve the background color with a batchGet request. What is the problem with doing it with `spreadsheets.get`?

Comment: It`s problem, because i have 10 Spreadsheets, and each of them has 1-10 sheets. I try load this sheets in my program, and almost always exceed data read quotas + that take more time.

Programm take data in 10 Spreadsheets and then user(10 users) can see this data in my app

Comment: Well, if it is not possible to make a batchGet request, maybe it can be done with some other request as well?

Because, with batchGet, I got a lot more free traffic than when I used spreadsheets.get

Comment: You can issue a `spreadsheets.get` call that returns only the fields you desire (like the sheet id and background color) and nothing else... Use the `fields` optional property.

Comment: See also https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/batch

Comment: Hello АлексейКостенко, what about the solution provided by the @tehhowch, doesn't that work for you?